# overflow auto no funciona

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo problema con un menú desplegable, cuando abro el sub menú "cumples y eventos" u "otros servicios" (cuando se ejecuta el codigo de muestra no se alcanza a ver porque se encuentra mas abajo, lo cual deja mas en evidencia cual es el problema con el scroll) se sale de pantalla y no se como colocar el scroll para que pueda bajar y ver asi porder ver las demas opciones.

**El problema se genera cuando le coloco al `header position:fixed`porque quiero que se mantenga visible cuando el usuario visite la pagina**

Probé colocar `overflow:auto` en tarjeta del menú que aparece `#cardMenu` pero no funciona.

```js
function displayMenu() {
  var display;
  var cardMenu = document.getElementById("cardMenu");
  display = cardMenu.style.display;
  if (display == "none" || display.length == 0) { /*|| display.length == 0  detecta el estado del menu*/
    cardMenu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    cardMenu.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayOs() {
  var display;
  var Os = document.getElementById("subMenuOS")

  document.getElementById("subMenuCyE").style.display = "none"; //////////*CIERRA MENU AL SELECCIONAR LA SECCION*/

  display = Os.style.display;
  if (display == "none" || display.length == 0) { /*|| display.length == 0  detecta el estado del menu*/
    Os.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    Os.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayCyE() {
  var display;
  var CyE = document.getElementById("subMenuCyE")

  document.getElementById("subMenuOS").style.display = "none"; //////////*CIERRA MENU AL SELECCIONAR LA SECCION*/


  display = CyE.style.display;
  if (display == "none" || display.length == 0) { /*|| display.length == 0  detecta el estado del menu*/
    CyE.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    CyE.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: frutiger-light, arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: #4C4C4C;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1100;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFD615;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #B0B0B0;
}


/*----------header / logo ---------------*/

header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1200;
  background: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header h1 figure a#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}


/*----------------------------MENU--------------*/

nav .ioMenuMovil {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav .ioMenuMovil img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 10px;
}


/*-----------------TARJETA EXIT------------------*/

nav #cardMenu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 78%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid #A7A7A7;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #A7A7A7;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1100;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav #cardMenu #hideMenu {
  width: 50px;
}

nav #cardMenu #hideMenu:after {
  font-family: "icomoon";
  content: "\ea0f";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: #808080;
}

nav #cardMenu ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4C4C4C;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 20px;
  display: block;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li a:hover {
  background: #E5E4E4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  color: #323232;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li#cYE:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: "\ea43";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 190px;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li#otrosServicios:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: "\ea43";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 190px;
}


/*----------------SUBMENUS-----------------------*/

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE {
  display: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 25%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE p {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  font-family: frutiger, arial;
  font-size: .8em;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE li:hover {
  background: #F2EDED;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  color: #323232;
  font-family: frutiger;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuOS {
  display: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 30%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuOS a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <figure>
      <a id="logo" href="index.html"><img src="imagenes/el punto logo.jpg" alt="El punto - estudio"></a>
    </figure>
  </h1>

  <nav id="ioMenu">
    <figure id="showMenu" class="ioMenuMovil" onClick="displayMenu()"><img src="imagenes/menu.png" alt="menu"></figure>
    <div id="cardMenu">
      <figure id="hideMenu" class="ioMenuMovil exit" onClick="displayMenu()"></figure>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li id="diseño"><a href="diseño_Grafico.html">DISEÑO GRAFICO</a></li>
        <li id="bolsas"><a href="bolsas_de_papel.html">BOLSAS IMPRESAS</a></li>
        <li id="carteleria"><a href="carteleria.html">CARTELERIA</a></li>
        <li id="cYE" onClick="displayCyE()"><a href="#">CUMPLES Y EVENTOS</a>
          <ul id="subMenuCyE">
            <li>Diseños personalizados de</li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#souvenirs">SOUVENIRS</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#tarjetas">TARJETAS </a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#pins">PINS</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#banderines">BANDERINES</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#mesas">MESAS DULCES</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#bolcita">BOLCITAS PARA CARAMELOS</a></li>
            <li><a class="ultimo" href="cumples_y_eventos.html#bolcita">CAJITAS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="otrosServicios" onClick="displayOs()"><a href="#">OTROS SERVICIOS</a>
          <ul id="subMenuOS">
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#papeleria">PAPELERIA COMERCIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#redes">MANEJO DE REDES</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#web">DISEÑO WEB</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#estampado">ESTAMPADOS Y BORDADOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#sublimacion">SUBLIMACION</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#pins">PINS PUBLICITARIOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#impresion">IMPRESION FOTOGRAFICA</a></li>
            <li><a class="ultimo" href="otros_servicios.html#tarjetas">TARJETAS Y SOUVENIRS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="contacto"><a onClick="displayFormContact('block')">CONTACTO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: no habia notado ese boton... gracias por el consejo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Porque no remueves el `padding-left`

```js
function displayMenu() {
  var display;
  var cardMenu = document.getElementById("cardMenu");
  display = cardMenu.style.display;
  if (display == "none" || display.length == 0) { /*|| display.length == 0  detecta el estado del menu*/
    cardMenu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    cardMenu.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayOs() {
  var display;
  var Os = document.getElementById("subMenuOS")

  document.getElementById("subMenuCyE").style.display = "none"; //////////*CIERRA MENU AL SELECCIONAR LA SECCION*/

  display = Os.style.display;
  if (display == "none" || display.length == 0) { /*|| display.length == 0  detecta el estado del menu*/
    Os.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    Os.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function displayCyE() {
  var display;
  var CyE = document.getElementById("subMenuCyE")

  document.getElementById("subMenuOS").style.display = "none"; //////////*CIERRA MENU AL SELECCIONAR LA SECCION*/


  display = CyE.style.display;
  if (display == "none" || display.length == 0) { /*|| display.length == 0  detecta el estado del menu*/
    CyE.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    CyE.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: frutiger-light, arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: #4C4C4C;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1100;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFD615;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #B0B0B0;
}


/*----------header / logo ---------------*/

header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1200;
  background: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header h1 figure a#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}


/*----------------------------MENU--------------*/

nav .ioMenuMovil {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav .ioMenuMovil img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 10px;
}


/*-----------------TARJETA EXIT------------------*/

nav #cardMenu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 78%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 240px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid #A7A7A7;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #A7A7A7;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1100;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav #cardMenu #hideMenu {
  width: 50px;
}

nav #cardMenu #hideMenu:after {
  font-family: "icomoon";
  content: "\ea0f";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: #808080;
}

nav #cardMenu ul {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4C4C4C;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 20px;
  display: block;
}

nav #cardMenu ul li a:hover {
  background: #E5E4E4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  color: #323232;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li#cYE:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: "\ea43";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 190px;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li#otrosServicios:before {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: "\ea43";
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 190px;
}


/*----------------SUBMENUS-----------------------*/

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE {
  display: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE p {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  font-family: frutiger, arial;
  font-size: .8em;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuCyE li:hover {
  background: #F2EDED;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  color: #323232;
  font-family: frutiger;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuOS {
  display: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#ioMenu #cardMenu ul li ul#subMenuOS a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <figure>
      <a id="logo" href="index.html"><img src="imagenes/el punto logo.jpg" alt="El punto - estudio"></a>
    </figure>
  </h1>

  <nav id="ioMenu">
    <figure id="showMenu" class="ioMenuMovil" onClick="displayMenu()"><img src="imagenes/menu.png" alt="menu"></figure>
    <div id="cardMenu">
      <figure id="hideMenu" class="ioMenuMovil exit" onClick="displayMenu()"></figure>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li id="diseño"><a href="diseño_Grafico.html">DISEÑO GRAFICO</a></li>
        <li id="bolsas"><a href="bolsas_de_papel.html">BOLSAS IMPRESAS</a></li>
        <li id="carteleria"><a href="carteleria.html">CARTELERIA</a></li>
        <li id="cYE" onClick="displayCyE()"><a href="#">CUMPLES Y EVENTOS</a>
          <ul id="subMenuCyE">
            <li>Diseños personalizados de</li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#souvenirs">SOUVENIRS</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#tarjetas">TARJETAS </a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#pins">PINS</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#banderines">BANDERINES</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#mesas">MESAS DULCES</a></li>
            <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#bolcita">BOLCITAS PARA CARAMELOS</a></li>
            <li><a class="ultimo" href="cumples_y_eventos.html#bolcita">CAJITAS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="otrosServicios" onClick="displayOs()"><a href="#">OTROS SERVICIOS</a>
          <ul id="subMenuOS">
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#papeleria">PAPELERIA COMERCIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#redes">MANEJO DE REDES</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#web">DISEÑO WEB</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#estampado">ESTAMPADOS Y BORDADOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#sublimacion">SUBLIMACION</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#pins">PINS PUBLICITARIOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#impresion">IMPRESION FOTOGRAFICA</a></li>
            <li><a class="ultimo" href="otros_servicios.html#tarjetas">TARJETAS Y SOUVENIRS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="contacto"><a onClick="displayFormContact('block')">CONTACTO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: disculpa alanfcm pero no entiendo tu aporte.... podrias explicar a cual `padding-left` te referis.... y por que?

Comment: Estas viendo tu codigo en un telefono?

Comment: si, pero igual se produce el problema si achico la pantalla de la pc....